# How to build an Angular 2 Tabbed document interface than incinerates routing?

Tags: angular

I am trying to find a way to build a tab component that integrates with the Router, there are plenty of Angular 2 tab examples but none that incorporate routing.

Examples cases assuming each tab is for editing a separate database record.

- User navigates to URL ./detail/1 if record 1 (tab) is not loaded then
  add as new tab, if record 1 tab is already loaded then select that
  tab.
- Browser back/forward would effectively allow you to switch
  back/forth between tabs

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [Brian's AC2015 connect talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4) about routing would help?

Comment: My sample components use a left menu backed by routes. I guess you can think of that as a form of tabs - at least conceptually.  It's not styled like a tab control, but still....http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you would want to do is child routes. 
Your parent component holds the dom for the tab controls and a router outlet

```
<tabs><tab>1</tab><tab>2</tab><tab>3</tab></tabs>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then just child routes for all the tab items. 
Unfortunately there has been some pretty big changes so none of my saved tutorial links are current with the beta. If you need more help I can try to do a plunker later.